# Express JS partial not loading stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, express

Here's what I've got in one of my partial files (head.ejs),

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../public/stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This is in the views --> partials folder.
The 'public' folder is two directories up.

There is nothing special in my app.js file; just the basic routing stuff.

Every time I run my app, styles.css is not applied. I can see it as one of the sources in the Chrome development tools, but it appears to be empty there.

Here is the styles.css file

```
body {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    color: red;
}
```

Here is the home.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <% include ./partials/head %>

        <title><%= title %></title>
    </head>

    <body class="container">

        <main>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
                <p>Welcome!</p>
            </div>
        </main>


        <% include ./partials/scripts %>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot give `../../` when serving from a server.

Instead, in your express add

`app.use(express.static(path_to_public_folder));`

And modify your `head.ejs` to

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```